# Nullifying Ancient Israelite Idols

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, bitul-batel-null, archaeology

Following up on a question raised on the Avodah list (see [here](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol29/v29n020.shtml) & [here](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol29/v29n021.shtml) under the subject “Destroying Idols”).

Archaeologists often dig up idols whose worshipers have abandoned them over the millenia. The archaeologists who take possession of the objects certainly have no interest in their worship. For the purposes of this question, I will assume (*l’kula*) that one or the other of these constitutes sufficient *bitul* (nullification) of the objects’ *avodah zara* status, rendering them no longer *ossur b’hana’a*.

[Edit: In a comment below, [JNF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1913/jnf) points out a [responsum by Rabbi Dov Lior](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=59922) which explicitly says that such artifacts are
“מותר, כי העבודה זרה הזו כבר התבטלה מן העולם”
*permitted, since this form of idolatry has vanished* (= been nullified) *from the world*.]

But what of *asheros* etc. discovered in Ancient Israel digs? Their worshipers were likely Jews, who cannot nullify *avodah zara*, as are many (most?) of the archaeologists. Is there a way to permit Jews to derive benefit from these historically important objects?

Comment: There have got to be Israeli posekim who have dealt with this question in practice. If we can identify who may have dealt with this, we may be able to contact them and get an answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses ...or see what they wrote.

Comment: Is studying them as an archaeologist even considered 'deriving benefit'?

Comment: @DoubleAA, similar to your comment - [About archaeology, but not in Isarel](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=59922), [more](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=44969)

Comment: @JNF sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: Not really, @HodofHod; the responsum does not address my question regarding _bittul_ of ancient Jewish idolatry.

Comment: @JCSalomon, But all the ancient idolatry that the Israelites practiced no longer exists (to my knowledge). I see no reason why that rule shouldn't apply here.

Comment: Thanks, @JNF, for pointing me to where I could find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Here, In India idolaters can pray hefty price to get back the Idols discovered by Archaeologists, to be installed in their temples . It is already a big black market which deals with sale of pagan Idols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted my question as a follow-up to the one mentioned in the comments above. Rabbi Dov Lior answered it at http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=77609 as follows (translation mine):

> אין ליהנות מהם, אך לימוד אינו נחשב הנאה – כי קול ומראה וריח אין בהם משום הנאה.‏
>   *One may not derive benefit from them, but study is not considered benefit – since* [as a general *halachik* principle —JCS] *“sound, sight, and smell are not considered benefit.”*

Comment: Did you intend to link to the previous question? Also, FTR the principle of "sound sight smell..." is from Pesachim 26a.

Comment: These antique idol artifacts now fetch millions and there is always a high chance of them getting stolen and be sold to black  market. Which can be purchased back by the current Idolaters. In India the temple committe does seek to get ancient Idols back to India, To be installed in temples